# json_encode JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES not working and still escaping slashes

Tags: php, character-encoding

My autocomplete search feature is broken because of how characters with accents are stored in the mySQL.

For example, in the mySQL column, É is stored like \u00c9

In the PHP, which receives the user's input and calls on mySQL, É is \xc3\x89

json_encode() almost works perfectly to take "\xc3\x89" and convert it to "\u00c9"

```
$clean = json_encode($criteria, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Except it converts it to "\\u00c9" and so the characters don't match even though they are both É.

The option JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES isn't working.  Why does it not keep another backslash from being added in front of the backslash?

How do I get this to work?

Edit: I just added the actual code and error log output below. code:

```
error_log("criteria vvvvvvvvvvvvv");
error_log($criteria);

$clean = json_encode($criteria, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);  

error_log("json_encode(criteria) vvvvvvvvvvvvvv");
error_log($clean);
```

The error log:

```
[Fri Aug 23] criteria vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv, 
[Fri Aug 23 \xc3\x89
[Fri Aug 23] json_encode(criteria) vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv, 
[Fri Aug 23] "\\u00c9"
```

Comment: I tried the code you provided in the edit part and this is my output `[24-Aug-2019 06:06:47 UTC] criteria vvvvvvvvvvvvv
[24-Aug-2019 06:06:47 UTC] É
[24-Aug-2019 06:06:47 UTC] json_encode(criteria) vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
[24-Aug-2019 06:06:47 UTC] "\u00c9"`

Comment: Please double check your `$criteria` variable. and make sure it's not holding this string `\u00c9` and if you managed to resolve the issue please let me know. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

First [JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-unescaped-slashes) is used to prevent escaping "SLASHES" `/` as the name implies, don't expect it to prevent escaping **back**slashes `\`

```
echo json_encode('/'); // prints "\/"
echo json_encode('/', JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); // prints "/"
echo json_encode("\\", JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); // prints "\\"
//note on line 3 : the input is 1 backslash
```

As you can see it prevents escaping slashes only , not backslashes

Regarding your problem, if you ended up by using `json_encode` with something like `\\u00c9` then you must have gave it this string as input `\u00c9` , `json_encode()` did nothing wrong , you feed it with the string "\u00c9" not the Unicode character`00c9`  and it escaped the backslash at the string beginning.

Your `$criteria` variable is probably holding a JSON encoded string like `"\u00c9"` that has been encoded without using the [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-unescaped-unicode) option, in other words don't use `json_encode()` twice.

check these examples, it could clear things out

```
echo json_encode("É", JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) . "\n";
echo json_encode("\u00c9", JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) . "\n";
echo json_encode("\xc3\x89", JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) . "\n";
echo json_encode("/") . "\n";
echo json_encode("/", JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) . "\n";
echo json_encode("\\", JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) . "\n";
```

This outputs

```
"\u00c9"
"\\u00c9"
"\u00c9"
"\/"
"/"
"\\"
```

[live demo](https://3v4l.org/dXHug)

Comment: Thanks for your input.  $criteria = "\xc3\x89";

Comment: @AndrewKoper And you get `"\\u00c9"` as output from using `json_encode("\xc3\x89")` ?

Comment: Yes - json_encode("\xc3\x89", JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) outputs \\u00c9 for me on PHP 7.0.1.  I've spent way too much time trying to get this char conversion to work.  Feel like I'm almost there, but this is frustrating.

Comment: Will this file `<?php echo json_encode("\xc3\x89", JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);exit;` output `"\\u00c9"` ? !

Comment: I will take any solution to convert \xc3\x89 to \u00c9 (French characters) at this point

Comment: If you made a simple file `test.php` with this content `<?php echo json_encode("\xc3\x89", JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);exit;` and request it, what will be the output ? `"\\u00c9"` or `"\u00c9"` ?

Comment: I can't do what you wrote exactly because of the codebase I'm in.  If we can IM or screenshare on another site, we can do that.  What I'm doing is below:

error_log("criteria vvvvvvvvvvvvv");
error_log($criteria);

$clean = json_encode($criteria, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

error_log("json_encode(criteria) vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv");
error_log($clean);

error log:
[Fri Aug 23] criteria vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv, 
[Fri Aug 23 \xc3\x89
[Fri Aug 23] json_encode(criteria) vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv, 
[Fri Aug 23] "\\u00c9"

Comment: OK check the [live demo](https://3v4l.org/dXHug) I included in the answer and play with it , you will find that `json_encode()` is expected to output `"\u00c9"` if you feed it with `"\xc3\x89"` or `"É"` and should output `"\\u00c9"` if you feed it with `"\u00c9"`.