# Search mySQL for special unicode characters with mysqli with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a search autocomplete feature which breaks when someone types a French characters, like É

É is stored like '\u00c9' - a unicode codepoint - in the mySQL table:

```
'id', 'term', 'count', 'words', 'locale'
'5218', '\u00c9COLORADO', '4', '1', 'fr-ca'
'5590', '\u00c9MADEUP', '1', '1', 'fr-ca'
'5511', 'EXCITE', '1', '1', 'fr-ca'
```

In the PHP, É is '\xc3\x89'.  I wrote the code below to convert it to unicode for the query so it would match.  On my system, json_encode() outputted "\\u00c9" so I had to str_replace() some of those additional characters

```
$andrew = json_encode($criteria);  
$temp2 = str_replace('"', "", $temp1);
$temp3 = str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $temp2);
$data = self::all( array( 'locale' => $locale , 'term' => array('$like' => $temp3."%" ) ), array('count'=>0,'term'=>2),0,12 );
```

When I type É in the search and error_log() the SQL query, it is:

```
SELECT * FROM search_term WHERE `locale` = 'fr-ca'  AND `term` LIKE '\\\\u00c9%'  ORDER BY `count` DESC, `term` ASC,
```

When I run that SQL query in mySQL Workbench, it works (the quadruple backslashes are necessary in the case of LIKE) and the result set is:

```
'id', 'term', 'count', 'words', 'locale'
'5218', '\u00c9COLORADO', '4', '1', 'fr-ca'
'5590', '\u00c9MADEUP', '1', '1', 'fr-ca'
```

But when I run that query in PHP with mysqli:

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

it doesn't return any results/matches.

How or why does mysqli_query() change the query so it fails?  How do I write this so that when the search character is É it matches with that character - how its stored - in the database?

Comment: Don't ignore your [primary issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633664/json-encode-json-unescaped-slashes-not-working-and-still-escaping-slashes), you have a sneaky bug in your code that turns `\u00c9` into `\\u00c9` and you should consider solving it rather than hacking it with `str_replace`, good luck!. regarding the problem in this question, your SQL fails in PHP probably because you used the backslashes inside a double quoted string `""` which triggers the PHP string Interpolation proccess, so this string `"\\"` is only 1 backslash and this string `\\\\u00c9%` has 2 backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Add that flag so that you will get the letter, not the Unicode code.